# Webhook for Jira Kanban

Tags: jira

Is there a way to add the column name to the webhook, so that when you change columns ( ie from "Selected for Development" to "In Progress" ) I can pass the new column name, and the user who moved the task

My Goal is to write a webhook that when a ticket is moved to "In Progress" I can trigger a clock in on my timeclock system, and when it is moved out, it triggers a clock out

Answer (score 0):

Ok, it looks like I was looking at the wrong area, the status is sent in the body

`$inputJSON = file_get_contents('php://input');`

Not in the Request

`$_REQUEST`